# Input submit is undisabled after first group checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had a form with many input groups, and all are hidden except the first group which is active. The submit button is actually next group and is it should be in any group disabled. My problem is that after the first group inputs has been checked the submit button (nextbutton) stays active which is not ok. Can anyone help?

```
<html>
    <p>Button should be enabled if at least one checkbox is checked</p>
        <div class="grp1">
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="option-1" id="option-1"> <label for="option-1">Option 1</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="option-2" id="option-2"> <label for="option-2">Option 2</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="option-3" id="option-3"> <label for="option-3">Option 3</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="option-4" id="option-4"> <label for="option-4">Option 4</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="option-5" id="option-5"> <label for="option-5">Option 5</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <h1>group 2 is hidden and will be display after group 1 input is checked and 
            button should be enabled if at least one check_box is checked</h1>
        <div class="grp2 " style="display:none;">
            <div>
                <input type="check_box" name="option-1" id="option-1"> <label for="option-1">Option 1</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="option-2" id="option-2"> <label for="option-2">Option 2</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="option-3" id="option-3"> <label for="option-3">Option 3</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="option-4" id="option-4"> <label for="option-4">Option 4</label>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" name="option-5" id="option-5"> <label for="option-5">Option 5</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <p>the submit button only appears if a group has a class=hasSubmit. and disabled only if a checkbox checked</p>
        <p>the problem is, after grp1 is checked and next to grp2 the submit button is undisabled</p>
        <input  class="nextButton" type="submit" value="Do thing" disabled>
    </div>
</html>
```

This is the code

```
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");

checkboxes.click(function() {
    submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
});
```

Comment: do you want the submit button disabled after all checkboxes are checked?

Comment: No, I want it enabled after the checkbox is cheaked for it to be able to move to next input group, but at the next group it should be also disabled until checkbox is checked. so on till final submit form

Comment: can you provide fiddle demo?

Comment: this is the example code. all i need is the first group to be separately treated as secound group  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/btmsnxeq/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I understood from your question:-

- By default only one group is visible and the button is disabled.
- When any checkbox of group 1 is checked the button should be enabled.
- On clicking the button group 2 becomes visible and the button is
  again disabled.
- If all the checkbox of any visible group is un-checked the button
  should again be disabled.

Based on this what you need to do is to disable the button when it is clicked after enabling the next section.

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function () {
    var doEnableButton = true;
    $('div.hasSubmit:visible').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find('input:checked').length === 0) {
            doEnableButton = false;
            return false; //break
        }
    });

    if (doEnableButton) {
        $('.nextButton').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        $('.nextButton').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});

$('.nextButton').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if ($('.hasSubmit:hidden').length > 0) {
        $('.hasSubmit:hidden:first').show();
        $('.nextButton').prop('disabled', true);
    } else {
        //Submit the page
        alert('Page submitted');
    }
});
```

For demonstration purpose I've moved the heading (`h1`) inside the `div.hasSubmit`. Also I've added three sections (that is 3 `div.hasSubmit`) in the following jsFiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/btmsnxeq/1/)

Comment: Taleeb i think your is what i need, but need to prove it first.

Comment: Sure. Don't forget to check the [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taleebanwar/btmsnxeq/1/). Let me know in case of any queries

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot it worked with your idea, i had to make some small modifications and that was it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First, correct your html layout and put your submit button inside of each group wrapper, which in your case is the element with class name `hasSubmit`.

Then find it on checkbox `click` event by traversing its parent container like so:

```
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']");

checkboxes.on("click", function () {
    // read it when checkbox click event is fired, instead of on page load
    var submitButt = $(this)
                     .closest(".hasSubmit")
                     .find("input[type='submit']");
    submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/gx8a5xfs/)